# How to make blocks floating image properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, floating

Here is my code:

```css
    .container {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .holder {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 75%;
      background-color: pink;
    }
    img {
      width: 25%;
      height: auto;
      float: left;
    }
    .data {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3>Title lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi</h3>
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Placeholder">
      <p class="description">Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero.</p>
      <div class="holder">
      <p class="data">Some Data 1</p><!--
      --><p class="data">Some Data 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would like the description and the data block float around the image. And the data paragraphs take 50% each (real project has more rows of data, but 2 data per row). And it looks great on huge screen:

[image]

But once we add more text to description OR narrow down the window size, the data blocks will start to go on a new line and since I set the holder to 75% width (100% - 25% for the image), the data paragraphs won't take 50% of the whole width already:

[image]

And I'm trying to fix this (To make the "Some Data 1" and "Some Data 2" take 50% each of the available space - image 1 is correct, image 2 is not) but can't find a way. Help me please. I need pure CSS solution please.

Comment: You could change the width of elements depending on screen size with CSS queries

Comment: @GuillermoCarone Thank you, but I never know when the text and data blocks will become floating the image. Imagine we have 10 same blocks, and description is everywhere different, one line there, 10 lines in the other place.

Comment: Should the text always be to the right of the image?

Comment: @PeterLeger No, the text should float. The image one looks great, the image 2 the only problem is that "Some Data 1" and "Some Data 2" are not 50% each. They don't take whole space available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the html is fixed this should work? Put the image inside a container and use flexbox to do the two cols beneath the text.

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.holder {
  display: flex;
  background-color: pink;
}

.block img {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.data {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Title lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi</h3>
  <div class="block">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Placeholder"> Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero.
    Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi.
    Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere
    non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero. Aliquam nibh metus, lacinia sed posuere non, ultricies in nisi. Cras pharetra felis libero.
    <div class="holder">
      <p class="data">Some Data 1</p>
      <p class="data">Some Data 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but when full screen and description is shorter than the image height, the pink data is under the image in your case. In my case, and in my code it was right after the description (please see image 1).

Comment: I see - if you remove width: 100% (or change to max-width:100%) in the holder class it should work no matter how long the text is. (I changed my suggestion above)

Comment: That's great! Thank you for the solution!